# Swift - dismiss then pop VC

Tags: ios, swift

How would I dismiss a modal View Controller and also its parent that was pushed?

```
self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
     self.parent?.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
})
```

This only dismisses the top modal.

Comment: where do you call these methods ?

Comment: Inside a login function

Comment: Please show the actual view controller hierarchy that's in force at the moment when you want to do this. Also, what's `self`? I assume it is the top view controller (the ultimate presented view controller) but let's be clear. Finally, what's the goal: do you want the user to see two events (dismiss and then pop) or just one (pop)?

Comment: Ok: HomeVC > SignIn/UpVC(push) > SignUpWithEmailVC(show). Ideally one pop, going all the way back to HomeVC from SignUpWithEmailVC. Is that enough info?

Comment: If SignIn/UpVC was _truly_ pushed, not presented, then there would need to be another view controller above HomeVC in the hierarchy, namely a UINavigationController. So is that the case and you accidentally omitted it from your description, or is the problem that there is actually no UINavigationController?

Comment: I definitely typed that wrong - it is HomeVC > (show) > SignIn > (present) > SignUpWithEmail.

Comment: If I were to push it, would that help?

Answer (score 0):

You can go another way.
First, you have `UINavigationController` in your Home view. So you can write an extension that will allow you to go to the controller, which is in the navigation stack.

I tried making an implementation like this:

```
extension UINavigationController {
    
    func routingPath(for controller: UIViewController) -> [UIViewController] {
        guard viewControllers.contains(controller) else {
            return []
        }
        var result: [UIViewController] = []
        for previousController in viewControllers {
            result.append(previousController)
            if controller === previousController {
                break
            }
        }
        return result
    }
    
    func performNavigation(toPrevious controller: UIViewController,
                           shouldDismissModals: Bool = true) {
        let previousViewControllers = routingPath(for: controller)
        guard !previousViewControllers.isEmpty else { return }
        viewControllers = previousViewControllers
        
        if shouldDismissModals, let _ = controller.presentedViewController {
            controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can make a special method for `UIViewController`:

```
extension UIViewController {
    
    func returnBackIfPossible(to controller: UIViewController? = nil,
                              shouldDismissModals: Bool = true) {
        navigationController?.performNavigation(toPrevious: controller ?? self,
                                                shouldDismissModals: shouldDismissModals)
    }
}
```

Then you need to pass a reference for a Home controller to all of the next controllers (or store it somewhere). Next, when needed, you can call to `homeViewController?.returnBackIfPossible()` method, which will close all modals and reset navigation stack.

Comment: I also advise you to read about the Flow Coordinator pattern, which solves many navigation problems

Comment: Ah ok I will look in to that. I thought there had to be a way to go back twice without 50 lines of code. I'll try your solution! I'm also flexible with how these are presented/shown. The first just has to be non-modal and the second one modal.

Answer (score -2):

What is non-modal parent exectly?

Is it a view controller pushed by the navigation controller?

If then, you must pop that view controller from navigation controller.

Comment: Yes sorry, it was pushed. Just clarified that in the question. I do try popping it as seen in the code but it does not work.

Comment: Please don't misuse the Answer field as a place to ask the OP questions.